# Update date in temporary table based upon parameter and last row date

Tags: t-sql, lag

I'm trying to update a date in a temporary table using a parameter and looking at the last row number's date.

```
DECLARE @multiDayCourseDaysBetween INT = 3;

CREATE TABLE #Courses(TempId INT IDENTITY(1,1)
                        , [Date] DATE
                        , CourseTypeId INT
                        , OrganisationId INT
                        , Reference VARCHAR(100)
                        , CreatedByUserId INT
                        , CourseTypeCategoryId INT
                        , TrainersRequired INT);

CREATE TABLE #TempDates(TempId INT
                        , [Date] DATE
                        , LagDate DATE);

INSERT INTO #Courses([Date])
Values('2016-06-01')

INSERT INTO #Courses([Date])
Values('2016-06-02')

INSERT INTO #Courses([Date])
Values('2016-06-03')

INSERT INTO #TempDates(tempId, [date], LagDate)
SELECT TempId, [Date]  
     , LAG(c.[Date],1) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) as LagDate
FROM #Courses c

UPDATE #TempDates
SET [Date] = DATEADD(dd, @multiDayCourseDaysBetween, LAG([Date],1) OVER (ORDER BY [Date])) 
WHERE LagDate IS NOT NULL
```

But I receive an error - 'Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.'

For example the original dates would be

```
2016-06-01
2016-06-02
2016-06-03
```

but I would need them to become

```
2016-06-01
2016-06-04
2016-06-07
```

based off of 3 as a parameter.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to achieve, with your source data, processing rules and desired output?  It appears you have got halfway through a solution and are now asking us how to complete it, whereas it looks as if a completely different solution would be preferable.

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the last statement to something like below :

```
WITH b AS (
SELECT
    TempId
    , [Date]
    , FIRST_VALUE([Date]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) as FirstDate
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS rowRank
FROM
    #TempDates
)
UPDATE b
SET [Date] = DATEADD(day, (rowRank-1)* @multiDayCourseDaysBetween, FirstDate)
WHERE
    rowRank > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for this!